# How do I replace "View page source" with "Edit on GitHub" links in sphinx_rtd_theme?

Tags: github, github-pages, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

How can I replace the `View page source` hyperlink at the top of my docs pages with a `Edit on GitHub` link when building a Sphinx site using the [sphinx_rtd_theme](https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme) theme?

I'm manually building a [readthedocs.io](https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)-like site [using GitHub Pages](https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2020/07/23/sphinx-rtd-github-pages-2/), but the link in the top-right of all my doc's pages still says "View page source" instead of "Edit on GitHub."

The [theme's documentation](https://sphinx-rtd-theme.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring.html) lists a few relevant options (`display_github`, `vcs_pageview_mode`, and `github_url`), but it provides no examples. I've tried setting them at the root of `conf.py` and in `html_theme_options` to no avail.

How can I tell the `sphinx_rtd_theme` theme to change the `View page source` link to an `Edit on GitHub` link on all my docs' pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use should set the `display_github`, `github_user`, `github_repo`, and `github_version` variables *inside* the `html_context` dict in `conf.py`. For [example](https://github.com/BusKill/buskill-app/blob/b604e23535bb27f1ecb0c3311a8c55bf34f88ef8/docs/conf.py#L99-L106):

```
html_context = {
  'display_github': True,
  'github_user': 'buskill',
  'github_repo': 'buskill-app',
  'github_version': 'master/docs/',
}
```

These variables are intended to be set directly in the `.rst` files rather than in `html_theme_options` or `conf.py` in general. To make this actually apply site-wide as if it were defined in *every* `.rst` file, just put it in [html_context](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-html_context).

See also:

- https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/529
- https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/blob/master/sphinx_rtd_theme/breadcrumbs.html